# Java Web services using axis or axis2?

Tags: java, soap

I have made API's and i want to do the webservice of it.It does not contain any database. so i dont need to learn jdbc. But the problem is axis is somehow not working properly in ubuntu.Java2WSDL tool is not working. So i switched to axis2. Again it is very vast and i'm freaking out. So my question is can i make axis work in ubuntu? And please help me and let me know if there is any other framework on whitch i cna work.

Comment: classnotFound error is coming.

Comment: IS there any other framework on whcih i can work?

Comment: If it's a `ClassNotFound` error something tells me you need a lot more fundamental knowledge in working with Java. You should ask about that error instead of flip-flopping between three frameworks. Java2WSDL / JAX-WS should be reasonably easy to use but they're geared towards WSDL-first development.

Comment: ClassNotFound-problems indicate you do not deploy properly.  Do you have a more experienced Java programmer around to ask?

Answer (score 1):

I've used both frameworks Axis 1, and 2 but about year ago decided to move my projects to [spring ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/) and I think you can try this framework too(just for SOAP) for REST services I am using [restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)

Comment: Same with me regarding the choice for SOAP, and totally agree. For me the big win is that Spring WS allows you to work with the XML model directly. The xml-to-bean mapping is supposed to help where in fact it hurts -- no XPath, for example. We had to create monstrous code to find a string three elements down (each step involved a list of elements). Using setters to populate the response is another pain in the (*).